# Apache Camel library will holding memory for long time?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, apache-camel, out-of-memory, verbose

I am using the `verbosegc` to capture some data and try to analyze the memory usage of my application.

I have a module that will pulling data from database or third party and put it into a list object then only return to front end for display.

When I choose the date to be date range, it will pull the data from database.
When I choose the date to be today date, then my application will send a request to `MQ` server, and the `MQ` server will response my application with `xml` message. The I will use Apache camel library to handle it.

Here is my verbosegc screen shot when pulling data from database:
[image]

As you can see, everytime when I trigger the search function, the memory usage will increase, and then drop back. So this is normal, and also what I expected.

[image]

And this is the `verbosegc` screen shot when pulling data from third party.
As you can see, after the memory increase, it will will horizontal there for a period, and then only drop back.

I suspect that the org.apache.camel.Exchange or org.apache.camel.Message or those object in Apache will holding the memory for longer time.

Here is some of my code to handle the `xml` message from third party:

```
/**
* Camel Exchange producer template
*/
protected ProducerTemplate< Exchange > template;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private < T > T doSend(final Object request, final String headerName,
            final Object headerObject,
            final SendEaiMessageTemplateCallBack callback)
            throws BaseRuntimeException {

        log.debug( "doSend START >> {} ", request );
        if ( this.requestObjectValidator != null
                && requestObjectValidator
                        .requiredValidation( requestObjectValidator ) ) {
            requestObjectValidator.validateRequest( request );
        }

        final Exchange exchange = template.request( to, new Processor( ) {
            public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                exchange.getIn( ).setBody( request );
                if ( headerName != null && headerObject != null ) {
                    exchange.getIn( ).setHeader( headerName, headerObject );
                }
            }
        } );
        log.debug( "doSend >> END >> exchange is failed? {}",
                exchange.isFailed( ) );
        Message outBoundMessage = null;

        if ( callback != null ) {
            // provide the callBack method to access exchange
            callback.exchangeCallBack( exchange );
        }

        if ( exchange.isFailed( ) ) {
            failedHandler.handleExchangeFailed( exchange, request );
        } else {
            outBoundMessage = exchange.getOut( false );
        }

        // handler outbound message
        if ( this.outboundMessageHandler != null ) {
            this.outboundMessageHandler.handleMessage( outBoundMessage );
        }
        if ( outBoundMessage != null ) {
            if ( outBoundMessage.getBody( ) != null ) {
                log.debug( "OutBoundMessage body {}", outBoundMessage.getBody( ) );
            }
            return (T) outBoundMessage.getBody( );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Because of this, my application was hitting Out Of Memory Exception. I am not sure is it because of Apache Camel library or not, kindly advise.

Other than that, when I open the `heapdump` file, there is 52% complain on the `com/ibm/xml/xlxp2/scan/util/SimpleDataBufferFactory$DataBufferLink`

And the other are complain on the "Java heap is used by this char[] alone", which is some sub category under `DataBufferLink` as well.

I google on this, all is talking about the xml message too large.

I have no idea on which way or which direction I should continue to troubleshoot, can kindly advise on this?

FYI, I am using camel-core-1.5.0.jar

Comment: Could you share more code? Huge optmization is to use InOnly exchangePattern. During first call of getOut is whole content `IN` message cloned. If you dont need original message, just overwrite `IN` instead of setting `OUT`. Also please mention Camel version, in [current javadoc](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html) I dont see method `Exchange#getOut(boolean)`

Comment: Hi @Bedla, I paste the whole method inside. FYI, my Apache is 1.5.0 version.

Comment: Camel 1.5.0 is really old (9 years ago), I dont think I can help you with it. You could try change ExchangePattern and use `getIn()`, to avoid cloning, but you should consider upgrade of Camel.